# discord python bot "The bot is not connected to a voice channel."

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, youtube

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import yt_dlp as youtube_dl

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("discord_token")
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''
ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' 
}
ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)
class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)
        self.data = data
        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = ""
    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]
            filename = data['title'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
            return filename

    @bot.command(name='join', help='Tells the bot to join the voice channel')
    async def join(ctx):
        if not ctx.message.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("{} is not connected to a voice channel".format(ctx.message.author.name))
            return
        else:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()
    @bot.command(name='leave', help='To make the bot leave the voice channel')
    async def leave(ctx):
        voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
        if voice_client.is_connected():
            await voice_client.disconnect()
        else:
            await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")

    @bot.command(name='play', help='To play song')
    async def play(ctx,url):
        try :
            server = ctx.message.guild
            voice_channel = server.voice_client
            async with ctx.typing():
                filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
                voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
                await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(filename))
        except:
            await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

I wanted to write a music bot for discord as an internship at the university.
I ran it on windows 10, all the libraries are new. the file is uploaded to the file system, but it is not played in the discord with the command !play

updated libraries, but it didn't help.
otherwise, the bot works as it should.
I installed the newest version of yt_dlp from github, but it didn't help. also updated the pip package manager to the latest version.